# Looking for apache web server configuration API

Tags: apache, api, configuration, vhosts

Is there an API available which I can use to configure Apache web server config file programmatically? I would like to access "vhost" and get/set properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [webmin](http://webmin.com/).

Comment: I don't see an indication at http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Apache_Webserver that this is something Webmin supports.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your best bet is to use tools like `sed` and `awk` to transform text files.

If you're using a Debian-based Linux distribution, there are a couple tools designed to script enabling and disabling modules and sites, described at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebianLikePlatform:

- `a2enmod` enables mods while `a2dismod` disables them
- `a2ensite` enables vhost sites while `a2dissite` disables them